# "phalcon" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo

Tags: cmd, phalcon

Estoy intentando crear un proyecto en phalcon, y al intentar crearlo me sale el error "phalcon" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo,
programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable.

He internado, poner en el path de las variables del entorno la carpeta donde esta el dll de phalcon, pero me sigue saliendo el error. No sé que mirar ya

En phpinfo, me sale que phalcon esta instalado

Comment: Buenas, podrías copiar la ruta que has copiado en el PATH? ¿En que idioma esta tu S.O?

Comment: Amigo tengo el mismo problema que tu, llego hasta ejecutar el comando de phalcon y me sale el "ERROR: Please run composer install" . Ya instalé el composer pero dónde encontraste el archivo installer.json y cómo lo actualizaste con el cmd?. Te agradecería muchisimo ya que para este error la documentación es escasa.

Comment: No lo arregle, me dieron una máquina ya con phalcon , no hubo manera

Comment: Fernando lam como solucionaste el probles de "ERROR: Please run composer install" sigo con este punto al colocar PHALCON en cmd

Comment: No lo arreglé, use una maquina virtual que ya lo tenia

Comment: Quisiera saber como solucionaste el último error "ERROR: Please run composer install" podrías darme más información acerca de installer.json y como inciarlo en el cmd. Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**phalcon-devtools**](https://docs.phalcon.io/3.4/es-es/devtools-installation) es una instalación adicional a la extensión PHP, donde en `PATH` agregas las rutas a `php.exe` y al `phalcon.bat` editado.

Comment: Hola, eso arreglo el problema del que hablaba, pero ahora tengo uno de nuevo. Intente utilizar el comando phalcon, y me pidio que tenia que instalar el Composer, lo instalé, y ahora me da el siguiente error: "ERROR: Please run composer install"  . Ahi ya no sé que hacer, si pongo en el cmd Composer me sale como si ya estuviera instalado es decir sale la versión que tengo, los comandos disponibles  etc..    Info: Utilizo Windows 10 y XAMPP

Comment: editado: solucionado, muchas gracias lo que debía es  buscar el installer.json e iniciarlo con el cmd, y ahí se actualiza